# Struts2 + tiles integeration with role based menus

Tags: struts2, tiles2

In my web app, i need to use Struts2 Tiles for role based access.
I have admin, agent, manager and user roles.

Based on the person logged in, i need to show him the extra links
in the menu.

After login with user if i try to browse admin link directly 
in browser the it should not allow to the user

If i have admin logged in and in tiles definition i use for an
attribute role="admin",
How come tiles know that admin has logged in, where does it check for
those roles?

Comment: What a security framework do you use?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29.

Comment: Hi thanks for all responses.
I am not going to use any security framework. i just use the struts2+tiles and created one Role interceptor.
So based on user logged in i need to show the menus.